# Can the word 'excruciating' be used with positive meaning

Tags: word-usage

I came across few sentences on the internet which are

1. He was excruciatingly funny.
2. He had an excruciating sense of humor.
3. The seconds ticked by excruciatingly fast.
4. He typed the letter with excruciatingly fast speed.
5. Excruciating Beauty

Names of few books

1. Excruciating bliss
2. Excruciatingly Perfect Weddings
3. The Fine and excruciating construction of the world

I am confused if some of the things above are meant as a complement.

I couldn't find any posisitve meanings attached to this word. So could you please explain if this word can be used with positive meaning. For example, in compliments etc

Comment: Look the word up in a dictionary. The dictionary definition is unambiguous as to the meaning of the word.

Comment: @δοῦλος - what makes you think i didn't look up in a dictionary? Can't you READ live examples that i gave. If you don't know the answers or don't want to answer, then dont make presumptions and keep your obnoxious advice to yourself.

Comment: I assume you didn't look it up because you did not mention a specific difficulty you had with a certain definition. You also did not state you had looked it up. And specifically stating that you did is pretty much protocol when asking about the meaning of a word.

Comment: Leo - Hold on. If you've looked up the word, you owe it to the community to share what you found. That's a common courtesy on ELL, something that we often exhort users to do. @δοῦλος has made a fair request; ELL is not a dictionary lookup service, and if you don't share what you've found, it can feel that way. [More here](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please/465#465). I think your question could be improved by adding a meaning from the dictionary if you already looked it up; that would have been preferred over calling the comment "obnoxious".

Comment: You also don't say where you found these; I'm particularly curious about #3. It sounds either incorrect, or wry and humorous – and it's hard to tell which. Given the right context, you can say just about _anything_. With no context here, it's hard to say if the word was used properly or not.

Comment: @J.R. - All the senetences are taken from google books. You might want to check it for yourself. Only sentence #4 is mine.

Comment: How is #3 used "with positive meaning"? If a team was losing a basketball game, then seconds might tick by "excruciately fast" – but that's not positive.

Comment: @J.R.- because I don't see any negative meaning to it. You might want to explain what is it.

Comment: "Excruciatingly" is excruciating.

Comment: With more information, I might invest some time weighing in with more than a comment. With nothing besides what you've given here, along with the exhortation to "check it out myself," you'll have to hope someone else is willing to do that for you.

Comment: @J.R.- you are taking it the wrong way. It's not an exhortation. I only said that because you were curious about the origin of the senetences. That's all. And I fail to see what more you expect. As far I am concerned this context should be enough to answer the question. For example what is 'Excruciating bliss' means ? It's a title of a book.

Comment: What meanings did you find that seemed negative? What is your understanding of the word?

Comment: @ColleenV - My understanding is that it is used with negative like excruciating headeache, pain. agony etc. Sometimes even to describe feelings like excruaciating boredum, inferiority complex, grief etc. Sometimes when desribing quality or quantity of something (which is in very bad state) like excruciatingly low profit/margin, excruciating sound, slow, fast etc. None of it describes a very nice condition of anything. Except the sentences in my question which are used as compliments. .....

Comment: Like, Excruciating beauty/bliss - I want to know what is the meaning here. Is it the bliss that I can't tolerate ? That doesn't make sense to me and I want to know if I could use this word to compliement something.

Comment: J.R., @Leo [The Fine and excruciating construction of the world](http://books.google.co.uk/books/about/The_Fine_and_Excruciating_Construction_o.html?id=VhYqMwEACAAJ&redir_esc=y) :-)

Comment: J.R., @Leo [and here too](http://bordercrossingsmag.com/article/the-fine-and-excruciating-construction-of-the-world-an-interview-with-ed-bu) :)

Answer (score 4):

In some instances you can substitute the word "painful" for "excruciating":

> He was excruciatingly funny

"translates" to

> He was painfully funny

In this case that means that

> He was so funny, I laughed so hard that it was *painful*

Which is a compliment. But in the very next example you give ("He had an excruciating sense of humor") it means the opposite: his sense of humour was painful (to have to hear) i.e. not very funny at all.

So as you can see, there is certain of nuance involved and the context is all-important. Someone who is painfully funny almost certainly does *not* have a painful sense of humour :)

Answer (score 2):

I will take a crack at this, Leo, because I think you misunderstand *excruciating|ly* in a way that a dictionary definition (e.g. "extreme or excessive") is not likely to clear up.

Excruciating|ly is not merely a synonym for "very" or "super" or "really" or "extremely":

**He typed super fast.

He typed very fast.

He typed really fast.

He typed extremely fast.

*He typed excruciatingly fast.**

*Excruciating* carries with it the idea that someone is *feeling* something.  So that this sentence:

**He typed excruciatingly fast.**

would mean that the typing was either painful to watch for some reason, or painful to do. Both of those are not impossible, of course (the typist could be typing an order for a court marshal or a letter expelling a student from a school, say, as the person in question looked on) but you need to know that there is such an implication, and if the context does not support it, it would be a strange usage.

P.S. You might find a few people using the word *excruciating* as if it meant "very", pure and simple, but they could be using it unidiomatically.